# .each index starts at 0, how can I change it to start at 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a .each function to build a dropdown list. I understand the basics of programming that the index of an array element will always start at 0. When I build this dropdown I need the first value to be a 1. This is what I have.

```
             $.each(codes, function(key,value){
        $('#columnD1').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + key + ' - ' + value + '</option>');
    })
```

So as expected I get 0 - Item1, 1 - Item2, 2 - Item3. But these codes are specific to certain values. 1 is for Item1 and 2 if for Item2. When I go to insert it wouldn't be a problem because I could fix it before the insert, the problem I'm having is that, I need the customer to see the code number for the item they are picking because in some place the value means nothing to the customer because they have the codes memorized.

Comment: I tried that. It concatenates it, doesn't add. So i then get 01,11,12.....

Comment: `(parseInt(key) + 1)`

Comment: because you need to do that between parenthesis (key + 1) .. also, double check if key is int and do `parseInt(key)` if not

Comment: All of these suggestions worked!!! Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $.each(codes, function(key,value){
    $('#columnD1').append('<option value="' + (key + 1) + '">' + (key + 1) + ' - ' + value + '</option>');
})
```

will give you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can add to key before you use it, just like in a `for` loop.

[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c1n0pcwg/)

```
$.each(codes, function(key, value) {
  key++;
  $('#columnD1').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + key + ' - ' + value + '</option>');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(codes, function(key, value) {
  if (key == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  $('#columnD1').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + key + ' - ' + value + '</option>');
})
```